# Repeat the same word multiple times for each option

Tags: seo, keywords, heading

I am wonder what is the better choice for multiple options.

For example consider the following case.

I have main section `Web Develepment`

And there are several options for this section.

1. Frontend
2. Backend
3. SPA
4. API

So what will be better ?
As I've mentioned above or

1. Frontend Development
2. Backend Development
3. SPA Development
4. API Development

I would be grateful for any help

Comment: Where do you want to use it? For a `meta`-`keywords` element?

Comment: @unor, no this is just a section of my site and these options are describing a section, as stated in my question Web Development includes Frontend, Backend, SPA and API. I used `h3` for the section name and `h4` for this items.
Sorry for `meta-tags` keyword, I accidentally choose it

Comment: Rule 1. Write content for users... not search engines.

Comment: We also have a vast amount of questions regarding keyword spam and stuffing already on Pro Webmasters, therefore this question is not unique and considered duplicate, but roll back... see my comment about rule 1. obey that and you can't go wrong... keyword stuffing is not the same as it uses to be... when writing quality natural content then you are bound to have keywords repeated many times in forms of elements.